# Broke file permissions and can no longer load webpages on server

Tags: centos, permissions, chown, plesk

I noticed an unusually large number of SSH attempts on my server so disabled the root login for SSH, created a new sudo user and confirmed I was able to log in without issues and elevate myself to the sudo user and root

I've since discovered that Plesk is unable to load the data from the server, the file permissions show as `10000:psaserv` and even after updating it to `root:psaserv` the servers files are still unavaliable. How can I undo this, is there a trick to setting the correct file permissions for Plesk?

I used the Plesk file privelages repair tool but it wanted to change it to `alex:psaserv` which is the user I created as a sudo user, but it does not make a difference. Please let me know if any logs or command output is needed to help resolve this

Since the issue started I restored the root user and can SSH as root without issue, still the above continues

Enviroment is CentOS7

Comment: Could you share some Plesk logs?

Comment: Try the repair tool after sudo su -  => you became root?

Comment: Yep, I restored the root user and I can SSH as root, still the repair tool generates the same outcome that permission is denied. Also tried running as ```sudo plesk repair all -n```

Comment: @SirMuffington Basically all the domains when it gets to the ```checking virtual hosts' file system``` says ```Failed to stat ***: Permission denied```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say file **permissions** and you change **ownership**

If Plesk repair tool didn't work, try setting back the default permissions

```
# find /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
# find /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Obviously, change `example.com` to correspond your directory

Comment: Getting closer, attempting to create a new domain produces the following:

```hosting update is failed: vhostmng-structure failed: Cannot create directory /httpdocs/test.domain: Permission denied```
```System error 13: Permission denied```

```drwxr-xr-x 26 root  psaserv    4096 Jan  5 11:52 httpdocs```

Comment: Are you running the command with sudo? See if this fixes your problem? https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003257014-Domain-or-subdomain-cannot-be-created-in-Plesk-Cannot-create-directory-System-error-13-Permission-denied

Comment: I'm already SSH'd in as root so I shouldn't need sudo, right? Tried the last link and also the Plesk Bootstrapper Repair Tool, no change

Comment: If you see # you're root

Comment: Then yes I'm root ;)

Comment: Can you create directory manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Revert the changes and make root accessible via SSH with key but not password.

If you wish to mess around with the current configuration I would think about editing `/etc/sudoers` file (with `visudo`) and giving localhost access to root login via SSH.